# Emberjs get one value from a collection of array

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, handlebars.js

I recently implement a small gallery of thumbnails with bootstrap, and I wanted to use the modal to be able to open the image in a popup in a bigger size.

So far I have the modal triggered but I have no idea how I can display that specific value for one image clicked.

This is my thumbnails generation :

```
<div class="row">
    {{#each value in images}}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
                <img src="data:{{unbound value.mimeType}};base64,{{unbound value.image}}">
            </a>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Here my modal (very basic one) :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">title of my image</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Images here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible with handlebar to retrieve one specific value to display inside my modal ?

I would know how to do it in js, but with ember and handlebars its kinda hard.

[edit] The controller of my page enquiry :

```
App.EnquiryController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isUpdating: false,

    actions: {
        showUpdateForm: function() {
            this.setProperties({ isUpdating: true });
        },
        customerUpdate: function() {
            this.setProperties({ isUpdating: false});
            var data = this.get('model');
            var obj = {
                customerName: data.enquiry.customerName,
                customerEmail: data.enquiry.customerEmail,
                customerPhone: data.enquiry.customerPhone
            };
            console.log(obj);
            Ember.$
            .post(host + '/enquiry/' + data.enquiry.id, obj, function(data) {
                console.log('DEBUG: Updating customer data OK');
            });
        },
        cancelCustomerUpdate: function() {
            this.setProperties({isUpdating: false});
        },
        tradeInUpdate: function() {
            var data = this.get('model');
            var obj = {
                mileage: data.tradeIn.mileage,
                valuationPrice: data.tradeIn.valuationPrice
            };
            console.log(data);
            Ember.$
            .post(host + '/enquiry/' + data.enquiry.id + '/tradeIn', obj, function(data) {
            console.log('DEBUG: Update TradeIn OK')
            })
        },
        summaryUpdate: function() {
            var data = this.get('model');
            var obj = {
                deposit: data.totals.deposit,
                discount: data.totals.discount
            };
            Ember.$
            .post(host + '/enquiry/' + data.enquiry.id, obj, function(data) {
                console.log('DEBUG: Update Summary OK');
            });
            console.log(obj);
        }
    }
});
```

I have a lot of data display there using the tabs bootstrap to hide and show it.

[edit2] The error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () {
if (!wasApplied) {
  Class.proto(); // prepare prototype...
}
o_defineProperty(this, GUID_KEY, undefinedDescriptor);
o_defineProperty(this, '_super', undefinedDescriptor);
var m = met...<omitted>...t'
```

[edit3] I got the good image link but I can't set the controller variable from the view..

```
var ClientView = Em.View.extend({
    actions: {
        selectItem : function(item) {
            console.log(item.uri);
            App.EnquiryController.set("imageSrc", item.uri);
        }
    }
});

{{#view ClientView}}
    <div class="row">
        {{#each value in images}}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" {{action "selectItem" this.value target="view"}}>
                <img src="data:{{unbound value.mimeType}};base64,{{unbound value.image}}">
            </a>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
{{/view}}
```

In my controller :

```
App.EnquiryController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    imageSrc: null
});
```

Comment: If you post your controller I can show you one solution. I normally use an action to open the modal, and then bind the model to a controller property like "selectedItem" and then use that within the modal handlebars template. I also prefer to set an item controller when iterating over a collection to avoid passing around the model within the action method...

Comment: I have edited the post for you with my controller.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem in other context. So what I done was

```
{{#view ClientView}}
<div class="row">
    {{#each value in images}}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <a class="thumbnail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" {{#action selectItem this target="view">
                <img src="data:{{unbound value.mimeType}};base64,{{unbound value.image}}">
            </a>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
{{/view}}
```

And then in the view for example:

```
var ClientView = Em.View.extend({
   actions: {
     selectItem : function(item){
       ClientController.set("imageSrc", item.src);
     }
  }
})
```

And in the modal i put this:

```
<img {{bindAttr src="ClientController.imageSrc"}}>
```

I hope that this can help you

Comment: I'm not sure to understand everything of your idea but after I implement it into my code I have this error : `Uncaught ReferenceError: ClientController is not defined` What should I do ? create a controller ? but to do what in it ?

Comment: Following your controller, instead of "ClientController" you should use your "App.EnquiryController" and add a variable "imageSrc" to store the value that you want.

Comment: But I have my entire model in item, and I don't know which image the user click on finally no ?And I tried to put a specific image (in base64) I have an error (I have edited the main post with the error).

Comment: Okay I have figure it out that I need to pass `this.value` instead of this from the action helper. But still, Its looks like I can't set my variable in my controller from my view. I have edited my post with my modification.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see what was your modification. Did you see if the function that you wan't to call in your action has parameters? I recommend to put a break point in the code (user the tools that google chrome has) and then see if the function it's called and what are the value of the parameters that are passed.

Comment: My problem is at this line : `App.EnquiryController.set("imageSrc", item.uri);` I have put a break point but the value of imageSrc from my controller is still at null because I have the error in the edit2..